# Qt debug show line numbers

Tags: c++, qt

I am a newbie programmer. Is there any way that I can print the File name and line number of my `qDebug()` output in Qt C++ code?
Currently, I have to manually write the filename every time I output a debug message.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following

```
qDebug() << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << "Your message";
```